# MySQL with Predicate Builder not working?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, predicatebuilder

I'm developing a small filtering based on the 3 fields. I'm also using the MySQL Connector in my MVC 3 project.

I've found a nice looking PredicateBuilder http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx . but it seems not to be working with the MySQL

```
 var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Order>();

  if(OrderID == 0)
      predicate = predicate.And(x => x.OrderID == 9); //an example, that order exist in the DB

  var result = (from x in db.Order select x).AsExpandable()
               .Where(predicate).ToList();
```

but the `result` contains 0 elements. Why ?

Answer (score 1):

Because you started with false and are using AND you will always get false.  Start with True instead:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Order>();
```